# HTML Page Loads, but shows up blank

Tags: python, html, webapp2, jinja2

I'm working on a project in Python, and I have part of the project working (where the user submits a post). I'm trying to make it so that when the user submits their entry, they get redirected to another page, which shows all the things they've posted. When I test this, I get redirected to the new page I made, but the page is blank. Here is my code:

```
 class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self, *a, **kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

    def render_str(self, template, **params):
        t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self, template, **kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class Entry(db.Model):
    subject = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    entry = db.TextProperty(required=True)
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)

class MainPage(Handler):
    def render_front(self, subject="", entry="", error=""):
        blog = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Entry ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10")
        self.render("entry.html", subject=subject, entry=entry, error=error, blog=blog)

    def get(self):
        self.render_front()

    def post(self):
        subject = self.request.get("subject")
        entry = self.request.get("entry")

        if subject and entry:
            e = Entry(subject = subject, entry=entry)
            e.put()
            self.redirect("/BlogPost")

        else:
            error = "To post a new entry, you must add both, a subject and your post"
            self.render_front(subject, entry, error)

class BlogPost(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("blogfront.html")


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage), ('/BlogPost', BlogPost)], debug = True)
```

This is just a piece of my code (I believe the error lies somewhere along those lines since my front page is working).

This is my blogfront.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
   <head>
    <title>Blog </title>
   </head>

   <body>
    {% for entry in blog %}
    <div class="entry">
        <div class="entry-subject">{{entry.subject}}</div>
        <label>{{entry.created}}</label>
        <hr>
        <pre class="entry-body">{{entry.entry}}</pre>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </body>
</html>
```

entry.html is loading while blogfront.html is not. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this. I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `Handler` here? I don't think the default `webapp2.BaseHandler` class has that method. Presumably you are rendering the Jinja template in it and writing it to `self.response`?

Comment: And presumably you need to pass in the `blog` object to the template; `blog = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Entry ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10")` and `self.render('blogfront.html', blog=blog)`.

Comment: `Handler` is a class that I wrote, that handles the template rendering. It takes `webapp2.BaseHandler` as an argument. In my MainPage class for example, `self.render` is a method created in the Handler class that renders the given template.

Comment: You may want to include that in your question so we can diagnose what goes on in it. The `BlogPost(Handler)` class is not enough.

Comment: If I do `self.render('blogfront.html', blog=blog)`, I get an Internal Server Error that says `NameError: global name 'blog' is not defined`

Comment: I will edit the question in a moment.

Comment: That's why I also told you to use `blog = db.GqlQuery()` in that method. :-)

Comment: Thanks, I did that just now, but I still get a blank page, after I submit the form.

Comment: Does loading `/BlogPost` manually, in your browser work, or is that a blank page too?

Comment: It's blank. However, if I open blogfront.html from my documents to the browser, I see all the jinja templates I used in my html file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your comments to questioners the issue is that while you define `blog` in the `render_front()` method, it's a local variable so it vanishes when the method returns. Try retrieving the data again in your `BlogPost()` method and pass that as the `blog` argument to `self.render()`. Without any blog data the template will indeed render as empty.

So your updated method might read:

```
class BlogPost(Handler):
    def get(self):
        blog = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Entry ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10")
        self.render("blogfront.html", blog=blog)
```

assuming that you want to see the same data you display in `MainPage()`, but you may well want something else.